# History homework class

Tags: php

I'm yrying to practice some OO PHP and I'm just wondering if what I'm doing is okay or not. Please tell me if there are any alarms in my method so that I can stop doing it and learn a better way.

In my conditional statement, I was following the rule of no `else` keyword, based on [this article by William Durand](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#2-don-t-use-the-else-keyword), which talks about Object Calisthenics.

I also don't know if I'm using the `abstract` properly, being that I learned it just a few minutes ago - but it works, so I suppose it's being used correctly.

```
<?php

        abstract class Homework
        {
            protected $coursesTaken = 0;
            protected $minimumCourses = 10;

            abstract function completedOrNot();
        }

        class HistoryHomework extends Homework
        {
            public function __construct($coursesTaken)
            {
                $this->coursesTaken = $coursesTaken;
            }

            public function completedOrNot()
            {
                if ($this->coursesTaken >= $this->minimumCourses)
                {
                    return "You completed the course in " . $this->coursesTaken
                    . " classes, but you only needed " . $this->minimumCourses
                    . " classes to complete the course! \n\n";
                }

                return "Sorry, you did not complete this course. You only took "
                . $this->coursesTaken . " classes, and you need a minimum of "
                . $this->minimumCourses . " to pass. \n\n";
            }
        }

        $student1 = new HistoryHomework(11);
        echo $student1->completedOrNot(); // You have completed the course in 11 classes, but you only needed 10 classes to complete the course!

        $student2 = new HistoryHomework(7);
        echo $student2->completedOrNot(); // Sorry, you did not complete this course. You only took 7 classes, and you need a minimum of 10 to pass.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's opinion-driven, but general points:

- You return large strings. Use `try`/`catch` for custom errors and warnings.
- Manage specific messages separately from your OOP (for example, language files).
- Separate layers, such as presentation, application, business logic, etc.

About the further structure: correct, but you didn't post serious logic.

There are many patterns to solve problems, such as Model-View-Controller (separating responsibilities), Adapter pattern, Factory pattern, etc. Read more [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns).

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly correct, because the objective of the abstract class are to define shared methods that other classes will at least implement.

This is one of the principles of SOLID. (I suggest reading them)

*Principle O: Open-Closed*, which means: *Objects or entities should be open for extension, but closed for modification*, if you want to extend some functionality just extend your program (interfaces and abstract classes) but never rewrite it.

Well done! Welcome to robustness and professional programming!

Answer (score 1):

Class looks perfect to me. Only thing I would suggest to keep the `else` block to maintain the best practices, which will also save you from some accidental errors. Like this:

```
                if ($this->coursesTaken >= $this->minimumCourses)
                {
                    return "You completed the course in " . $this->coursesTaken
                    . " classes, but you only needed " . $this->minimumCourses
                    . " classes to complete the course! \n\n";
                } else 
                {
                    return "Sorry, you did not complete this course. You only took "
                    . $this->coursesTaken . " classes, and you need a minimum of "
                    . $this->minimumCourses . " to pass. \n\n";
                }
```